# How can I show an encoded video file in Mediaplayer in Android?

Tags: android, video, stream, android-mediaplayer

I have a video file that is encoded. For example the first bit of each byte is reversed. I want to read this video file, change the first bits and send the decoded result to Mediaplayer.

How can I do that? How can I create and pass this stream to media player without saving the decoded data on storage?

It is important that I do not want to save a decoded copy of my video and play it on media player. I want to play encoded video directly on mediaplayer using streams or other possible ways.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer: NO, there is no way to do that** *(obviously by my point of view)*

You cannot reproduce from a "custom" stream  by manipulating the data just before passing it the `MediaPlayer`.

**Why?**

The official `MediaPlayer` API which is closest to the one needed to achieve your goal is the following:

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(yourFile);
mp.setDataSource(fis.getFD());
//...
```

This snippet allows to play a file starting from a `FileInputStream`, but more precisely from the underlying `FileDescriptor`. The [FileDescriptor](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileDescriptor.html) is a class which is marked as **final** (and it is reasonable because it has to deal with the underlying OS), so you cannot override anything.

**Possible workarounds?**

1. As you already pointed out, you can try to modify the real file "in-place" while reproducing the video with the standard `MediaPlayer` (without creating a deep/separate copy of it): it's very tricky but plausible.
2. Try to use another player object: [ExoPlayer](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer.html) (which is a new standard Android API) or [Vitamio](https://www.vitamio.org/en/Download/)
3. Try a pure native solution (NDK + Android source), which I will not recommend ;)

---

**UPDATE: detail about the 1st workaround**

Assuming that "the first bit of each byte is reversed" you can use a [**FileChannel**](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html) to **manipulate the whole file "in-place" while reading it**. You should use a `FileChannels` created from a [RandomAccessFile](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) created in mode "*rw*" in order to be able to **read/write simultaneously**.
This *pre-elabaration task* can run on a separated thread (or inside an `IntentService`, which is more fashion and reliable); you can wait for few seconds after the elaboration begins and then starting the playback by passing the `File` reference to the standard `MediaPlayer` (you need to tune this waiting period considering how fast is the elaboration, like a streaming buffering but easier because performance are almost stable). 
In this way you don't need to wait the end of the pre-elaboration before starting the playback.
When the playback stops or you close the app, you need to undo your work by calling the same pre-elaboration task on the played file in order to restore it to its original state.

I hope that this hint can be useful.

Comments and precisations about my answer are welcome, I will update my post if I'll find more information.

Comment: Can you explain more about the first solution?

Comment: @breceivemail I've edited the answer with my suggestion on the 1st workaround. let me know if it makes sense for you

Comment: Thanks but it is not a reliable solution. User can turn the device off and after that turn it on and copy the decoded file.

Comment: I think I should think about ExoPlayer. I will test it if you do not have any easier solution.

Comment: @breceivemail You are right but consider this: if you do a fine tuning, by knowing the current playback position you can start reverting the file to the original state while playing. In this case, you will need to keep track of your changes (maybe inside a Preference) in order to know which part of the file are reverted or not. In this way, the whole process will be more reliable.

Comment: Maybe I do not understand correctly. Can I decode and encode dynamically on a same file? For example can I decode 1000 first bytes, then encode 1000 first byes and decode the second 1000 bytes while mediaplayer is playing my video file?

Comment: @breceivemail Yes, but the constraint is on the `MediaPlayer` because it surely uses a buffer. That's why a fine tuning is needed.

Comment: There is a problem. Some video file headers are at the end of file so mediaplayer reads some parts of the file which is not detectable for us

Comment: @breceivemail Arrrg.. This is just one more trick to add in your pipeline: the pre-elaboration starts to decode an arbitrary-sized tail of the file and after that it re-starts from the beginning (you can do that easly with `Filechannel` because you can seek to any position of the file in constant time ).